# UICollectionViewCell is reordered or disappear on scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a problem with UICollectionView. I created a collection with FlowLayout and I'm trying to resize only second item to make it width to 2xcellWidth. It's ok when View is appear, but after that, when I'm scrolling and back to top, my cell are disappear, reorder or change it width. It's totally weird behave. 
So to be clear: I created collection view, scroll to bottom and when I back to top, I see my cells are in some weird place like this:

before: 
[image]

after:
[image]

```
class MapEventsViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width

    let options = [Options(id: "", value: "28-03-2017 10:54:01"),
                   Options(id: "", value: "Berlin Strasse 6A 00-000, Berlin", isDoubled: true),
                   Options(id: "Status", value: "-"),
                   Options(id: "Prędkość", value: "40km/h"),
                   Options(id: "Licznik", value: "250000km"),
                   Options(id: "Napięcie", value: "15V")]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.frame.size.height = 170

        let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()   

        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 1, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 1)
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 1
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
        layout.scrollDirection = .vertical

        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.register(MapEventCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        collectionView.isScrollEnabled = true
        collectionView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
        collectionView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.flexibleWidth
        collectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(white: 0.90, alpha: 1.0)
        collectionView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = true


        self.view.addSubview(collectionView)

    }

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return options.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! MapEventCell

        cell.awakeFromNib()

        cell.id.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)
        cell.value.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)

        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        if indexPath.row == 0{
            cell.value.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10)
            cell.value.frame.origin.y -= 6
        }

        if indexPath.row == 1{
            cell.value.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10)
            cell.value.frame.origin.y -= 6
        }

        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let thisCell = cell as! MapEventCell

        thisCell.id.text = options[indexPath.item].id
        thisCell.value.text = options[indexPath.item].value
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
//        print("sizeForItemAt")
        let cellWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 3 - 1
        if options[indexPath.item].isDoubled{
            return CGSize(width: cellWidth * 2 + 1, height: 40)
        }
        return CGSize(width: cellWidth, height: 40)
    }
}

class MapEventCell: UICollectionViewCell{

    var id: UILabel = UILabel()
    var value: UILabel = UILabel()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        print("addViews")

        id.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: contentView.frame.width, height: 16)
        id.textAlignment = .center
        value.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 16, width: contentView.frame.width, height: 20)
        value.textAlignment = .center

//        id.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)
        id.textColor = UIColor.lightGray

//        value.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)

        contentView.addSubview(id)
        contentView.addSubview(value)

    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        id.removeFromSuperview()
        value.removeFromSuperview()
    }

}
```

**UPDATE**
I've solved this problem by calculating frame of each element in cell at CellForItemAt indexPath. So now it looks like this (and worked):

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! MapEventCell
    cell.awakeFromNib()
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    if indexPath.section == 0{
        cell.value.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: (screenWidth / 3), height: 30)
        if options[indexPath.item].isDoubled {
            cell.value.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: (screenWidth / 3) * 2 - 2, height: 30)
            cell.value.textAlignment = .center
        }
        cell.id.isHidden = true
        cell.value.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10)
    }else{
        //cell.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: (screenWidth / 3) - 1, height: 40)
        cell.id.isHidden = false
        cell.id.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10)
        cell.value.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 12)

    }

    return cell
}
```

But now I'm not sure is it good solving. I know that every time cells are reusing, so my question is, are there better solutions for this problem?

Comment: Yes there are better solutions, I am curious why you call the method `cell.awakeFromNib()`?

Comment: To read UICollectionViewCell from it own Controller. I was created a method in MapEventCell, which is adding subviews, and the method has called in override init(frame: CGRect) - in this case I haven't to call cell.awakeFromNib(), but the issue is still existing...
@ReinierMelian could you propose some better solution for that?

Comment: `cell.value.frame.origin.y -= 6` everytime this is called, it removes 6, because cells are reused. That's why at some point, it's all messed up. Better use NSLayoutConstraint on `MapEventCell`, and maybe a Xib (o give visual indications)? A simple solution: add a property CGRect initialValueFrame: calculate it in the `init` of the cell. Then, in `prepareForReuse()`, do `self.value.frame = initialValueFrame`. Do the same for the other frame.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However it's not working for me. One important thing is that my collection view first row has 2 item, rest of all has 3 column. I share collection on two sections. So I have to calculate it in case of section number. That's why I can't make calculations in MapEventCell. 
If I tried to initialize value and id in init, it provoke the same issue with first row mess. 
@Larme tak a look on update - there is no more calculations cell.value.frame.origin.y -= 6.